# Calculate the number of requests per second using Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I want to calculate the number of requests per second for a particular URL from a Spring Boot 2 application, also the time taken for each request (latency) in milliseconds. We can see the following metrics from Actuator/Prometheus:

```
http_server_request_config_seconds_count  
http_server_request_config_seconds_sum
```

I'm confused how to plot this in Prometheus to get my result. Do I need to add a histogram or quantiles?

Answer (score 13):

If you only care about the request per seconds, you don't need anything related to the quantiles.

```
irate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{uri="/your-uri"}[5m])
```

And if your are interested in the response time overall:

```
irate(http_server_request_duration_seconds_sum{exception="None", uri = "/your-url"}[5m]) / irate(http_server_requests_duration_seconds_count{exception="None", uri = "/your-url"}[5m])
```

If you want more precised metrics (quantiles) you can refer to the [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/#quantiles).
e.g:

```
histogram_quantile(0.99, sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{exception="None", uri = "/your-uri"}[5m])) by (le))
```

Answer (score 3):

Both `http_server_request_config_seconds_count` and `http_server_request_config_seconds_sum` metrics are [counters](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter). E.g. they increase over time and may reset to zero when the service, which exports these metrics, is restarted.

The `http_server_request_config_seconds_count` metric shows the total number of processed requests since the last service restart.

The `http_server_request_config_seconds_sum` metric shows the total sum of request durations for all the processed requests since the last service restart.

If you need to calculate the average RPS over the given lookbehind window, then you need to use [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) function:

```
rate(http_server_request_config_seconds_count[5m])
```

This query uses 5 minute lookbehind window in square brackets for calculating the average RPS. It is possible to use any desired lookbehind window according to [time durations syntax](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-durations).

The following query shows the average query duration over the last 5 minutes:

```
increase(http_server_request_config_seconds_sum[5m])
  /
increase(http_server_request_config_seconds_count[5m])
```

It works in the following way:

1. It calculates the sum of request durations over the last 5 minutes with [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function.
2. It calculates the the number of requests over the last 5 minutes with the `increase()` function.
3. It divides the sum of request durations by the number of requests and gets the average request duration over the last 5 minutes.

Queries above may return multiple results if `http_server_request_config_seconds` metric is scraped from multiple targets.  If you want calculating the summary RPS and average response time across all the scrape targets, then [sum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) aggregate function must be used.

The following query returns the summary average RPS across all the scrape targets during the last 5 minutes:

```
sum(rate(http_server_request_config_seconds_count[5m]))
```

The following query returns the average response duration across all the scrape targets during the last 5 minutes:

```
sum(increase(http_server_request_config_seconds_sum[5m]))
  /
sum(increase(http_server_request_config_seconds_count[5m]))
```

Note that the `sum()` must be used independently for the left-hand and right-hand sides of `/` operator.

Answer (score 1):

To enable quantiles an additional configuration property needs to be added to your application.properties, substituting in whatever quantiles (not percentiles, despite the name) you’re interested in:

```
management.metrics.web.server.request.autotime.percentiles=<comma-separated list of quantiles>
```

If we configure the property as 0.95 this would result in the following metric at /actuator/prometheus:

http_server_requests_seconds{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/doit",quantile="0.95",} 0.023068672
The tags used with this metric are the same as above, except now we also have a quantile tag, which can be used to query the metric.

The following graph is generated in Prometheus from the http_server_requests_seconds{quantile="0.95"} query:

ref：
https://tomgregory.com/spring-boot-default-metrics/